# C# Slack Bot to Slack Channel - using Slash command and not chat

Tags: c#, json.net, slack, slack-api

I'd like to send a slash command to a channel of my choice.

I'm using the Newtonsoft Json.NET serializer from NuGet. Currently, I have the following code:

```html
            string messageToSend = @"/Kyber test task here";
            string channelToSendTo = "#general";
            
            var urlWithAccessToken 
 = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/TOKEN/SPECIFIC/STUFF";

            var client = new SlackClient(urlWithAccessToken);

            client.PostMessage(username: "MyBot",
               text: messageToSend,
               channel: channelToSendTo);
```

And the SlackClient.cs

```html
    public SlackClient(string urlWithAccessToken)
    {
        _uri = new Uri(urlWithAccessToken);
    }
  
  
  
public void PostMessage(string text, string username = null, string channel = null)
    {
        Payload payload = new Payload()
        {
            Channel = channel,
            Username = username,
            Text = text
        };
        
        PostMessage(payload);
    }
  
  
public class Payload
{
    [JsonProperty("channel")]
    public string Channel { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

It currently just says "/kyber test task here" instead of calling the /kyber slash command.

I've seen the undocumented [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) command, but it doesn't appear to work with the Slack API now.  I was hoping there was another way to do it without using the Legacy App functionality, since it surprises me that I was unable to find an example newer than about 3-4 years ago that didn't use it.

Comment: Just to rule out the problem, can you try do `/who` (showed in the documentation) to see if it actually runs the command or just type `/who`? It could be that the library you use doesn't support /kyber command.

Comment: When I try that, it just says /who in the chat and does not execute the command (from my C# project).  I can do /who manually in the slack channel just fine and it displays the list of users, as intended.

Comment: If no one else replies the answer here. I would recommend to consult with the library author via github issues. Maybe you need to run different command or something.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the answer, but I asked Slack support about it.  They replied:

> It sounds like you might be asking about allowing an app to send a message containing the slash command, in order to trigger the slash command.
> If so, I'm afraid that's not possible. Instead, since all slash commands essentially trigger a specific API endpoint, you'll need to contact the developers of that slash command to see if they make that endpoint publicly accessible so that you can create your own app mechanism to try and trigger commands to those endpoints.
> I'm sorry that I don't have better news for you on this. I hope that info might help you to move forward though. Thanks for checking in on this.

So I think the answer is that the App I'm using doesn't support that functionality, and Slack doesn't/won't either.  Thanks anyways for the help.