# App Slash Command in Slack using chat postmessage API

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

This question may be existing already here: [C# Slack Bot to Slack Channel - using Slash command and not chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348186/c-sharp-slack-bot-to-slack-channel-using-slash-command-and-not-chat)

But that question is already 3 years ago and maybe this is supported now or someone has made a work around.

Basically, using Slacks's chat.postMessage API, we can execute slash command of an App like that of Bitbucket's repository connect command.

Comment: I do not think that is possible since the purpose of a /slash command is to trigger a user interaction with a Add-in.